# jQuery UI: how to reset dialog title?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to clear the dialog title, but `$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', ' ');` doesn't work as expected, it will make the dialog title very thin, what is the proper way to clear the title?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#b1").click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'test');
                });
                $("#b2").click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', ' ');
                });
                $("#b3").click(function(){
                    alert($('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title'));
                });
                $("#dialog").dialog();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dialog">
            <p>This is a dialog.</p>
        </div>
        <input id='b1' type='button' value='set title to test'>
        <input id='b2' type='button' value='clear title'>
        <input id='b3' type='button' value='alert(title);'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert a [non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), not just a `space`. I copy/paste it from the wikipedia page:

> U+2007   figure space (HTML: &#8199;). Produces a space somewhat equal to the figures (0–9) characters.

I make an interactive sample:

```js
            $(function() {
                $("#b1").click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'test');
                });
                $("#b2").click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', ' ');
                });
                $("#b3").click(function(){
                    alert($('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title'));
                });
                $("#dialog").dialog();
            });
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        
        <div id="dialog">
            <p>This is a dialog.</p>
        </div>
        <input id='b1' type='button' value='set title to test'>
        <input id='b2' type='button' value='clear title'>
        <input id='b3' type='button' value='alert(title);'>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work! I actually tried another unicode space character before posting this question but it didn't work, this one does the magic.